# Does openSSO need to be on a separate server as my webapp?

Tags: tomcat, opensso, openam

I'm new to web programming - I apologize for any unclear or incorrectly used terms.

I'm trying to protect a simple GWT app with a login/pass system with openSSO.

I was under the impression that I could have openSSO running in the same Tomcat server as my app. E.g.
http://domain.com:8080/opensso
hhtp://domain.com:8080/myGWTApp are both valid.

After a successful installation and configuration of both openSSO and the associated Tomcat agent for my app, I am getting ConnectionException in my Java EE agent. Is it the case that the openSSO server needs to be up and running when my app starts? Does this mean I need one SSO server and one apps server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  OpenSSO should be up-and-running when your application starts, and yes it should be running on a different server.